# Is there a way to get the user name set for siri?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I need to get the name of the user of an iPhone, but the only related things to get data from the device related to the user is using the UIDevice Class, but all I can get is the device name.

Anybody know how I can get the user's name without asking to them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no Siri API today.

See this for more info: http://www.quora.com/Siri-API/Does-Siri-have-APIs-that-can-be-used-today